# How express and vue projects work together?

Tags: javascript, express, vuejs2

I have HelloWorld express app:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express() 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})
const port = 8000;
app.listen(port,()=> console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

and i have HelloWorld vuejs app, created following this guide [Vue HelloWorld example](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create). It listens port 8000 and shows interface with quick reload feature.

Both apps can't run at the same port for now.
But i want my vue app sends request to my express app and get response from it. 
Please, tell me how to do it in right way?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Run both apps on different ports.
Install cors npm module in express js to allow calls from the different server.
In vue js use axios to request on express js server.